# Meaning of following notation

Tags: notation

I came across the following notation used for a function $f$:
$$|f|_{L^\infty}$$

What does this notation denote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the ess sup norm (short for "essential supremum").  It denotes $sup\{y|\mu\{x||f(x)|> y\}>0\}$